# Why are sleeper buses so rare in some parts of the world, yet common in others?

Tags: buses, night-transport

Although night trains frequently have sleeper services, until recently, I had never come across sleeper buses.  [The man in seat61 reports their existence in Laos](http://www.seat61.com/Laos.htm#Hanoi%20to%20Vientiane), and apparently they are [used in N-America and Europe to transport bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_bus).  It seems [Megabus UK has a service between London and Glasgow](http://www.megabusgold.com/The-Gold-Experience/Sleeper-Service/).  According to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/29092/2509), those are pretty much unique in Europe.

Why are sleeper buses so rare in Europe and North America?  They are reportedly quite common in Latin America and parts of Asia.

Comment: Because they are more expensive to operate and hence will be more expensive to ride.  Plus stopping every 2-3 hours anyway.

Comment: @Karlson Do you mean more expensive than night buses without sleepers, or more expensive than sleeper trains? More expensive need not be a reason to not exist if the additional price leads to additional service. I would certainly have booked a sleeper service for my long-distance buses in North America, if they had existed and cost less than ~50$ extra (which means around 2x the price I paid for a seat). Probably for more than 50$ extra still. I wonder if regulations are a problem.

Comment: More expensive then regular buses.  Trains are more expensive to operate in general.  As far as North America/US is concerned the Union and DOT rules will require buses to stop every 2-3 hours so what's the point.

Comment: @Karlson I don't see the link between the stopping frequency of buses and the non-existence of sleeper services.  They don't force passengers off the bus.

Comment: Ever tried sleeping with the lights on

Comment: Germany outlawed sleeper coaches in
2006 following several serious motorway
accidents when passengers were thrown from
coaches. Lawmakers said sleeping coach
occupants could not be restrained adequately
with seatbelts.
In 2010, a German court rejected an
operator’s appeal alleging that the ban
contravened EU law. Judges said there was
no EU-wide legislation on sleeper coaches,
meaning German law took precedence.

Comment: There are regular scheduled sleeper bus services from Penang, Singapore, Caracas, Guatemala, and I'm sure some other places I haven't been!  I think they are not quite as rare as they seem to you...probably just an issue of geography.  In places where not everyone owns a car they're doing all right...tourism helps too.

Comment: @Karlson As I understand this British sleeper bus, each bed has its own curtain (like sections on a train) so the corridor light shouldn't be too bad. I've slept (badly) overnight on both Eurolines and Greyhound, the interruptions where the lights were on for a short interval in the middle of the night were not the main reason I slept poorly.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Hmm, do all of those places have in common that there exist little to no passenger train infrastructure? Sleeper trains have a long tradition in Europe, although recently many have been displaced by fast day trains and cheap flights. I believe they're still quite strong in eastern Europe and South Asia. Day trains are and remain very popular in Europe so I don't think car ownership is the issue.

Comment: Unions are killing it off in Australia, allegedly...

Comment: @GayotFow Your comments could be turned into an answer.  Did the unions in Australia have similar arguments to the legislators in Germany?

Comment: Why can't I bounty this question?!

Comment: They are very common in Japan, maybe because long-distance trains are very expensive.

Comment: @gerrit, no, the Aussies have health and safety issues for the drivers; Germany is about passenger safety.  But I'm also thinking that M&A (viz, vertical integration) in the travel industry may be the largest factor, but can't find anything supporting my guess.

Comment: @JoErNanO I suppose it's too new?

Comment: @GayotFow Why do they argue that sleeper buses are more dangerous to the driver than classic night buses?  Or do neither exist?

Comment: @fkraiem I rephrased the question according to your comments.

Comment: Health issue for the driver is not a good reason. As all other jobs that require night shift also introduce some bad effect for health. If it's really bad then you should suppress operation of military, police, hospitals, guards... at night as well. Good sleeper buses have 2 drivers so that each will only be awake for a few hours.

Comment: In 10 years or so we should have fully automated buses, potentially bringing sleeping buses everywhere.

Comment: As a passenger, i consider trains to be more comfortable, yet more expensive. In some places, like Latin America there are sleeper buses, simply because trains are very (very!) rare. For instance, in a country as big as Brazil, I'm not aware of any long distance passenger train service, except for Metro/subway or touristic train routes [like this one](http://www.tripadvisor.com.br/Attraction_Review-g680210-d2049990-Reviews-Maria_Fumaca_Giordani_Turismo-Bento_Goncalves_State_of_Rio_Grande_do_Sul.html). For long distances all you have is either planes or buses...

Comment: I think this question is far too broad to be answered here. The reason there aren't sleeper buses in the US is no doubt influenced by multiple economic and cultural factors. Americans don't like riding the bus. Period. Those who do generally do so because they can't afford anything else. If they could afford a sleeper bus, they'd probably take a flight instead.  The economics and cultural "acceptance" of bus travel varies greatly by country, or even region of a country. There's far too much to explore here than is reasonable in a SE post, I believe.

Comment: it depends on laws and legislation, people's attitudes and culture, infrastructure, supply and demand, at the end of the day these services need to be economically sustainable

Comment: Part of me wonders how much the culture affects it, along with the way the respective services are run. Thailand has both sleeper buses and trains, but the buses are (generally) more straightforward and less likely to have huge delays. The budget given to infrastructure is also a possible culprit...

Comment: Japan, having arguably one of, if not the, best rail systems in the world has a huge amount of overnight buses run by many companies across the country. They have now phased out all but two sleeper train services (which are likely to be cancelled in the next few years) as the mixture of LCC flights, cheaper bus fares and new timetables for the Shinkansen (bullet train ) services have been implemented. Quite possibly due to either road infrastructure, competition from LCC's or even things like the various Greyhound bus shootings/hijackings, cultural reasons etc. could be a reason.

Comment: It seems a very broad question to ask why approximately half the world doesn't do (very much of) something or have services that are available elsewhere...

Comment: 7 years on the megabus gold sleeper in the UK no longer exists. https://www.route-one.net/news/megabus_gold_dual_purpose_sleeper_day_coaches_to_end/ Due to lack of demand, most likely because they are not very comfortable and there is a good day train to Glasgow and the high end/time conscious is catered to already by the Caledonian sleeper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual commercial problem with sleeper *trains* is that the vehicles carry significantly fewer passengers than a seated vehicle and often either cannot be used at all in daytime, or are stuck at the same capacity as they have overnight.

The standard capacities for a European train carriage (26m long, with a toilet) are 36 for a sleeper, 54 for a couchette (roughly hostel-equivalent accomodation), 57 for a first-class seated carriage and 76 for a second-class seated carriage. The proportions will be similar for buses.

This means that the sleeper cars have to earn enough money from fewer passengers doing one overnight journey to match several daytime journies for a seated car - but the sleeper is generally more expensive to buy and more expensive to run (overnight vs daytime pay for the driver, and usually attendants in addition to the guard/conductor). This means that fares have to be a lot higher for a sleeper to make a profit. Sleeper trains have been run by European railways as a loss-making public service, but are being wound down as railways become more commercial.

Sleeper buses are going to have a similar set of problems - they will cost more to buy than a conventional bus, and will carry fewer passengers, and will have higher running costs (at the very least, the bedding will need to be changed and washed) - and they can't be used for daytime journeys, so they will probably sit idle in the middle of the day.

That means they will need to charge a substantial fare premium over a seated coach to make a profit (at least double and more likely triple the fare). In countries where there are good alternatives like car rental or cheap flights, then this is likely to limit the market.  Unless they can offer something distinctive (like an early morning arrival in a city where the airport is not allowed to have night landings), they may struggle to get passengers.

If there isn't an existing regulatory regime for getting sleeper buses approved, then the costs of getting the government to create one are likely to be too great for an operator to be prepared to pay - and note that some countries prohibit them entirely. Germany is a really important one, as many of the likely routes in Europe would run through Germany, but the German government banned sleeper buses in 2006.

Comment: The sleeper buses can definitely be used during the day. You just need long distance connections. I've done it before and it worked very well

Answer (score 12):

You'll find few people claiming that buses are more comfortable than trains, all things being equal.

A train network is much more expensive to initiate than a bus network, which works on a road network built, not for the purposes of transferring people or goods by bus, therefore is much more likely to exist, anyway.

Ergo, as mass long distance leisure travel is more recent than train travel, it follows that sleeper buses are more likely to exist in areas where long distance travel is typical yet where trains do not exist.

Latin America has virtually no train connections, while large cities are few and far between. Parts of SE Asia have no train connections with some distances being sizeable. Europe is relatively small and has both good train and cheap air links. (Africa, generalising, has no good long distance public transport of any kind).

My knowledge, in relation to this, of North America is limited. As per @gerrit's comment's below, it is possible that, if relevant laws allow, there is room for a competitor to offer night bus sleepers in North America.

Comment: That is indeed generalising.  My friend in Kenya was quite happy with his overnight bus ride in a modern, airconditioned bus that departed right on time.  Not a sleeper bus, though.  Not sure if your comment about Africa is necessary.

Comment: Everything is a generalisation. And, anyway, following my argument, long distance African sleepers could exist on routes that are relatively popular. Examples could be Mombassa - Nairobi (which also has a train connection), Nairobo - Kampala, several routes in Southern Africa.

Comment: It doesn't explain the absence from North America, though.  Only a very limited number of routes in North America have sleeper trains, so in many ways one might expect a similar situation to South America.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with North America to authoritatively comment on that, but how common are night busses in North America? Furthermore, I'm under the impression that North America does have a low cost airline network.

Comment: Night buses are quite common in North America. The Greyhound and Megabus networks are a lot denser and more frequent than the Amtrak (train) network. Low-cost airlines only fly to a limited number of tourist destinations like Las Vegas, Florida, Mexico, but if you're in a college town in the mid-west travelling to Chicago, the choice is a cheap (possibly overnight) bus, an expensive flight, driving, or in rare cases, a train. Anecdotally, it was cheaper for me to take a bus from Iowa City 1150 km to Toronto (from 70$, 17 hours), than a round trip airport transfer to Eastern Iowa Airport (75$).

Comment: Clearly, my theory of everything is not yet applicable everywhere. I would venture that with the Greyhound and Megabus networks in place, it will be hard for a third party to compete, not on price, but on quality (sleeper busses will sleep fewer people and thus will be costlier per person). Yet, if regulations don't prevent this, it sounds there's room for a competitor offering just that.

Comment: @MastaBaba Megabus already is competing on quality.  I've been told by someone who rode all 3 repeatedly a few times that Megabus's seating quality and on time reliability was far better than Greyhound and comparable to Amtrack's.  Her preference was for Amtrack if a cheap ticket was available, Megabus otherwise; with Greyhound an option of last resort.

Comment: But, is MegaBus competing with night sleepers?

Comment: While this is pure conjecture, I'd assume that the sleeper segment is largely covered by [Amtrack's sleeper trains, which seem to connect most states](http://www.seat61.com/UnitedStates.htm#.VfdJm-FyxyE). The cost of buying and running a fleet of sleeper busses even between only a few states would presumably outweigh any profit to be gained from filling the gap in the market.

Comment: @Lilienthal A sleeper on Amtrak's sleeper trains is *expensive*, because you have to book at least an entire roomette, you're paying all meals included, etc..  The only other alternative is a seat (much better than a seat on the bus, but nowhere near a sleeper).  Unlike most European sleeper trains, there is no hostel-style equivalent of a bunk in a shared room.  I've often wondered why not, but it should be possible to operate sleeper buses with bunks considerably cheaper than Amtrak's roomettes.

Comment: @gerrit Yes, that site indicated as much. I'm assuming that the idea of night bus travel is considered so uncomfortable/cheap that the idea of paying even slightly more to travel in a bit more comfort isn't that appealing while the routes with high volumes of long-distance travel are adequately covered by other affordable options (flights, rental). That said, we'd probably need to see market studies to know for sure. I'm assuming they exist but they're probably not public.

Comment: For North America, there is now a new company that's starting to offer [sleeper bus service](http://www.sleepbus.co/) between San Francisco and Los Angles. Leaves at 11pm, arrives around 5-6am, but they'll let you stay on until 9 should you feel the urge to spend more time on a bus. I can't say it makes a ton of economic sense to me: that air route is served by very frequent service with a lot of competition covering several airports in both regions, leaving intercity bus service for highly cost-sensitive customers, but hey, if they want to try to make it work, all the power to them.